# Issue with Insertion Sort Code

Tags: java, sorting

I'm writing an insertion sort method and I've run into some trouble -

```
private int getInsertionPosition(int currPos){
  int val = this.toSort.get(currPos);
  int index = currPos;
  for(int i = 0; i < currPos; i++){
      if(val < this.toSort.get(i)){
          index = i;
      }
  }
  return index;
}
private void move(int from, int to){
  int num = toSort.get(from);
  toSort.remove(from);
  toSort.add(to, num);
  System.out.println("Moved " + from + " to " + to);
}
public void performSort(){
  for(int i = 1; i < original.length; i++){
      move(i,getInsertionPosition(i));
      System.out.println(this.toSort.toString());
  }

}
```

I have a couple debug lines in there, printing out what index it's moving the elements of the arraylist from / to.

However, I get weird operations where sometimes it's moving seemingly arbitrary values to the wrong index, i.e.

"
[7, 18, 29, 3, 2, 4, 24, 18, 18, 13]
Moved 3 to 2
[7, 18, 3, 29, 2, 4, 24, 18, 18, 13]
"

Any help? I'm 99% sure the issue is with the getInsertionPosition method.

Comment: You should learn how to use a debugger.

Answer (score 0):

Yes your problem is in `getInsertionPoint`. You need to return the first index that has a value greater than the value. At the moment you are returning the last index that is greater than the value.

Try:

```
private int getInsertionPosition(int currPos) {
    for (int i = 0; i < currPos; i++) {
        if (toSort.get(currPos) < this.toSort.get(i)) {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return currPos;
}
```

Alternatively, if you are familiar with Java 8 streams:

```
return IntStream.range(0, currPos)
    .filter(i -> toSort.get(currPos) < toSort.get(i))
    .findFirst().orElse(currPos);
```